# What are the differences between non-compiled and compiled ASP.NET pages

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build

Got a situation where we have a working production website that is moving to a different group of servers. The team handling that site has gotten it to work without any issue (we can test it all day long.) The problem they are encountering is that in order for it to go live it has to compile/build without any errors.

It's an ASP.NET site built on the 2.0 framework. Not super complicated and to my knowledge it has never had to be compiled before now. Any changes done on the current production site involve just copying over .html and .aspx files.

What are the ramifications of not compiling the site before it goes live and deploying it as is? The team handling the deployment is saying that it's a security issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS will compile .as?x files as they are requested.  You can have a bug in one and not find it till the page is loaded.  If you create a web project (instead of a web directory), when you go to publish, a dll is compiled of ALL your code in the site.  None of the .vb files are necessary at that point and only the compiled dll is requred in your /bin folder.  This guarantees you DON'T have syntax errors in your code and you won't experience compile errors.

Comment: Ah, that is helpful. So if a minor change is needed the whole site would need to be recompiled and deployed as a .dll instead of static .aspx and .html files?

Comment: Yes, but the compile process for the dll is infinitely faster than compiling every individual page in a web directory.  Essentially the web directory compiles a dll for every page.  Every page that loads has to load its individual dll.  The web project loads that single dll once and it stay loaded for the life of the application.